# Rounded Corners without using imagse

Tags: html, css

Are there any methods out there that do not use images to implement rounded box. That also works in all the IE browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this site. Works like a charm.

http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Not for every version of IE. But: why would you bother showing round corners to all browser? Sites like Twitter have just gave up on that: you don't have a good modern browser? You don't get to see my iCandy.

Answer (score 1):

There are several VML and HTC-based hacks out there, including [DD_roundies](http://dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/) - searching Google for `Internet Explorer Rounded Corners CSS` or `Internet Explorer Border Radius CSS` should get you some other results.

Personally, I just allow Internet Explorer to render my pages differently: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [jQuery corner plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/), if it is using IE, it creates some divs with backgroud, but if it using another browser like Chrome, or Firefox it uses a the native CSS atribute "radius".

Also this plugin can create a lot of interesting effects for your corners. 
Take a look, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : [CurvyCorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/)

Answer (score 0):

This method does not use images and works everywhere but uses a LOT of code to do it:

http://spruce.flint.umich.edu/~jalarie/jaa_kcm.htm

Answer (score 0):

This may not directly address your specific request, but it is a point worth discussing.

If it's not a do-or-die requirement to have rounded corners in IE, it's actually ok to be comfortable with the fact that you won't have rounded corners for IE users. The benefits you gain with going with CSS3 rounded corners (small code, easy maintainability, tight control) outweigh the potential of an IE user being disappointed he or she didn't get the rounded corners.